# Can you seed a seekable prng in order to force it to generate a given subsequence of values?

Tags: sequences-and-series, random

Melissa O'Neill, (in her PCG prng papers), makes reference to prng "party tricks" where she says that you can seed a prng appropriately in order to force it to generate a sequence that contains, (at some point), a desired subsequence of values. She goes on to show a prng that "contains" the contents of a .zip file in its sequence.

In her 2018 blog, Ms. O'Neill says that she will have a further article that explains how to accomplish this "party trick", but she has not published anything further on the subject.

Can anyone explain how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
CBruce